# check if text exists in text box jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to check if the text exists in text box jquery

I need to check if the text exists in the input box,if checking text is not exist thend append new data

I have tried with below code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#item_inv_desc").change(function(){
            var item_inv_desc = $('select[name=item_inv_desc]').val();
            if (item_inv_desc == 7) 
            {

                var invoice_number = "123456789";
                //I need check if text "CRN" exists in text box
                var data=$('#invoice_number:contains("CRN")')
                if(data)
                {
                     //if text "CRN" exist no need to append data 
                }
                else
                {
                     //if not exist
                     $("#invoice_number").val(invoice_number+"CRN");
                }
            }
       }); 
    })

    //Html
    <input type="text" id="invoice_number"  value="">
```

I am having problem when try to insert append value it adds extra CRN number to invoice number,I need to avoid duplicating,

Comment: Try show us the corresponding HTML code, second off, look into `indexOf()`

Comment: Edit this  `var data=$('#invoice_numbe:contains("CRN")')` to `var data=$('#invoice_number:contains("CRN")')`

Comment: Try with "if(data.length > 0)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) with the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) of the text box:

```
var data = $('#invoice_number').val().includes("CRN")
```

or, for older browsers, use `indexOf()`:

```
var data = $('#invoice_number').val().indexOf("CRN") !== -1
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#invoice_number").change(function() {
    var invoice_number = "123456789";
    var data = $('#invoice_number').val().includes("CRN");

    if (data) {
    } else {
      $("#invoice_number").val(invoice_number + "CRN");
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="invoice_number" value="">
```

Comment: Sir, actually I have to find text "CRN" from the number like 123456789CRN, Input box value will be like 123456789CRN

Comment: @ManjunathCa you should be using `replace` check my answer

Comment: @ManjunathCa -- see my updated answer. Try adding some value to the input which contains/doesn't contain `CRN` and observe the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

@Manjunath
var data=$('#invoice_numbe:contains("CRN")')

"r" is missing when you are checking below
var data=$('#invoice_numbe:contains("CRN")')

and use

```
var data=$('#invoice_number').val().indexOf("CRN");
        if(data>-1){
            // donot add CRN
        }
```

Comment: @ManjunathCa add ; at the last to close the statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove all the digits and get the text only from the value of the input text. If you want that on button click then add that block of code inside the `click` function:

```js
var data = $('#invoice_number').val();
var res = data.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="invoice_number"  value="123456789CRN">
```